# MonoDevelop C# - Error while compiling class file

Tags: c#, linux, class, monodevelop

I am trying to compile a basic test class in MonoDevelop version 5.0.1.1. See the following code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace testproject
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass
        {
            string name;
            public string Name
            {
                get {return name;}
                set {name = value;}
            }
            int[] integers;
            public int this[int i]
            {
                get {if (i < 5) {return integers[i];} else {return -1;}}
                set {if (i < 5) {integers[i] = value;}}
            }
            public TestClass(string _name)
            {
                name = _name;
            }
            public override string ToString ()
            {
                string output = name + ":";
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    if (i != 4) {output += " " + i.ToString() + ",";}
                    else {output += " " + i.ToString();}
                }
                return output;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is a very basic test class that I created to try out MonoDevelop on Linux (I just switched from VS2017 on Windows). When I try to compile, I get the following error(s):

> /home/main/mono-cs/projects/test-project/test-
>   project/TestClass.cs(3,3): Error CS1519: Invalid token '{' in class, 
>   struct, or interface member declaration (CS1519) (test-project)

and

> /home/main/mono-cs/projects/test-project/test-
>   project/TestClass.cs(1,1): Error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, 
>   or end-of-file expected (CS1022) (test-project)

I double checked, and all curly braces have proper corresponding ones. Any insight?

Thanks all!

Comment: MonoDevelop 5.x is tool old. Use MonoDevelop 7.x and Mono 5.x. The compiler (Roslyn now) should work just like the Windows side.

Comment: `integers` is never initialized, you'll get a null reference exception when trying to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `public TestClass` ,Which is Repeat adding in nest `TestClass`
2. initialize `integers` otherwise you'll get a runtime error.(thank for @Ron Beyer remind)

Here

```
namespace testproject
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get {return name;}
            set {name = value;}
        }
        int[] integers;
        public int this[int i]
        {
            get {if (i < 5) {return integers[i];} else {return -1;}}
            set {if (i < 5) {integers[i] = value;}}
        }
        public TestClass(string _name)
        {
            name = _name;
            integers = new int[100];
        }
        public override string ToString ()
        {
            string output = name + ":";
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (i != 4) {output += " " + i.ToString() + ",";}
                else {output += " " + i.ToString();}
            }
            return output;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize `integers` otherwise you'll get a runtime error.